# MySql Self Join Count

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, self-join

i have a question concerning an MySQL Query. There are two tables, Persons and Married.

```
Persons:
ID
SurName
FirstName 
ID_Father
ID_Mother

Married:
ID
PersonID1
PersonID2
Marriage
Divorce
```

PersonID1 is always Male and ID2 is always female.

My Goal is getting a list containing FirstName, SurName and number of kids of all women currently or once married to Person with the ID = 1. Somehow I can't put it together in one Select statement.

Here are the two statements i've been using so far.

> SELECT  FirstName, SurName, ID FROM Persons  WHERE ID in( SELECT
>   married.PersonID2 from married where married.PersonID1 = 1);
>
> SELECT    Persons.ID_Mother as ID,    count(Persons.ID_Mother) as
>   NoOfChildren From Persons group by Persons.ID_Mother;

Thanks in advance

http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3661/vwqxeg8a_png.htm

Comment: Number of kids is not in your schema?

Comment: You have to calculate it 2nd Select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query do the job.

```
SELECT 
 woman.FirstName, 
 woman.SurName, 
 count(kid.ID) AS kids 
FROM Persons AS woman
INNER JOIN married 
 ON married.PersonID2 = woman.ID
LEFT JOIN Persons AS kid
 ON kid.ID_Mother = woman.ID
WHERE married.PersonID1 = 1
GROUP BY woman.ID
```